# List in two columns

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I'm trying to display a list in two columns. My thought was avoid tables.

```
div #DocumentList .Preview {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

and put each item in one of these div's inside a container div.

I though it was working as 4 items and 1 item come to their place but to my surprise when there are 3, and I can presume with 5, 7..., the "spare" one goes to the right

I don't get it. I would like to avoid extra reckonings in the view checking each item and deciding whether it should go right or left (I understand it's not a big deal, but if I could avoid it I think would be cleaner)

Comment: Have you thought about [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/column-count)?

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle example? It sounds like something else causing to appear to the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE 8 or greater (and of course, all other browsers)

```
.item{
    display: inline-block;
    width:49%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try CSS Multi-Column layout

```
div {
    -moz-column-rule:3px outset #ff00ff; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-rule:3px outset #ff00ff; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-rule:3px outset #ff00ff;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: [Column Rule at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/column-rule)

Comment: I'm not saying that it doesn't work as I only copy pasted for the moment. I will try harder though as it didn't come properly. But fotanus's solution worked fine. Thanks (didn't know about that wc3 neither)

Comment: Yes, combined with the column-count and other stuff mentioned in the links it works, but i will stick to fotanus solution as works for IE8 (requirement) and for this I had to change slightly the not very well organised css. Thanks!